# Why is my socket closed on Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets

**THE GOAL**
I am currently developing my first "real" Android application which accesses a server running on my own cluster. The base functionality is perfectly working but now I wanted to implement an automatic reconnect every 5 minutes.

**THE PROBLEM**
For this purpose, I made a TimerTask executing a method which handles the reconnect stuff. The server output tells me that the reconnect works fine because I can see "Login Successful". But as soon as the reconnect task executes, I see this exception in the ADB output:

```
08-13 14:15:18.805  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at net.dreamcode.android.dreampush.PushActivity$3.run(PushActivity.java:228)
08-13 14:15:18.810  19568-19617/net.dreamcode.android.dreampush W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It is pretty clear what it means, I am not new to network programming and Java in general. But I can't see the point where I am closing the socket before starting the listener thread.
Of course, on reconnect, I close the socket but I reopen it and as I already stated, also the login via Authentication Token works perfectly so the reopening of the socket also works.

**CODE**
Here are the methods involved in the process (shortened code):

```
private void initServerConnection() {
    try {
        Thread serverConnectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socketToServer = new Socket();
                    socketToServer.connect(new InetSocketAddress("emerald.dream-code.net", 25565));

                    if (socketToServer.isConnected()) {
                        connectionState = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    connectionState = false;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        serverConnectThread.start();
        serverConnectThread.join();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doLoginProcedure(final String username, final String password) throws Exception {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketToServer.getOutputStream()));
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketToServer.getInputStream()));

    // Save the username for further usage
    PushActivity.username = username;

    // Write the login command in additional thread to have the GUI free of lags
    Thread loginThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writer.write("LOGIN " + username + " " + password + "\n");
                writer.flush();

                // Read the response which is "failure" or "success" depending on the correctness of the login credentials
                String loginResponse = reader.readLine();
                if (loginResponse.equals("success")) {
                    // Set the login flag
                    isLoggedIn = true;

                    // Receive the login token for automatic logins in this session
                    authToken = reader.readLine();

                    // Get the old messages
                    messages.clear();
                    int messagesToReceive = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

                    List<String> notifiableMessages = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= messagesToReceive; i++) {
                        String messageFromServer = reader.readLine();
                        messages.add(messageFromServer);

                        if (i > readMessageCount) {
                            notifiableMessages.add(messageFromServer);
                        }
                    }

                    notifyUser(notifiableMessages);

                    readMessageCount = messages.size();
                }
                else {
                    isLoggedIn = false;
                    socketToServer.close();
                    initServerConnection();
                    // Notifiy user of failed login
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    loginThread.start();
    loginThread.join();

    if (isLoggedIn() && !isListenerRunning()) {
        displayMainContent();
        reconnectTask.startReconnectTask();
    }
}

private void displayMainContent() throws Exception {
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Register the list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Button reconnectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    reconnectBtn.setOnClickListener(new ReconnectButtonListener(this));

    ArrayAdapter<String> contentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);
    Log.d("SWAGGERINO", "" + messages.size());
    listView.setAdapter(contentAdapter);

    if (!this.isListenerRunning()) {
        this.startListener();
    }
}

private void startListener() {
    isListenerRunning = true;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable listenerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                String input;
                while (!(input = reader.readLine()).equals("exit")) {
                    if (!isListenerRunning()) {
                        break;
                    }

                    final String tmp = input;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            addListContent(tmp);

                            if (!getPushActivity().isInForeground()) {
                                List<String> notification = new ArrayList<>(1);
                                notification.add(tmp);
                                notifyUser(notification);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Thread listenerThread = new Thread(listenerRunnable);
    listenerThread.start();
}

private void stopListener() {
    try {
        socketToServer.close();

        reader = null;
        writer = null;
        socketToServer = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And of course the method which handles reconnect:

```
public void doRelogin() {
    stopListener();
    initServerConnection();

    try {
        doLoginProcedure(username, authToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    startListener();
}
```

**ALREADY CHECKED**
The flow is: `doLoginProcedure()` and then `startListener()`. In `doLoginProcedure()`, everything works fine because the user gets logged in on the server. So I checked if the server closed the connection after login, but it wasn't.

I also have a cleanup task on the server for deleting doubled/inactive clients and checked if the server maybe deleted the wrong clients, which also wasn't the case.

I am really out of clues how to fix this problem and would appreciate help. If I missed some code, please comment and I will add it.
*Thanks in advance*

Comment: I cancelled the app because I need to learn lot more about Android first. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to get my head around the logic of the code ...

---

But one thing that I've noticed is that you do this kind of thing in a couple of places:

```
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){ ... });
     thread.start();
     thread.join();
```

This usage of threads is pointless.  You could achieve exactly the same effect by executing the body of the `Runnable.run()` method.

Indeed, it is worse than pointless, because if the `run()` method throws some unchecked exception that isn't caught and logged in the `run()` method itself, then that exception is liable to go unnoticed.  And, it is *possible* that that might be happening here ...

But even if not, the redundant threading is expensive, and makes your code more complicated and harder to read.

---

The only other thing I can think of is that the client side may not be getting the correct login response line.  That would cause it to think that login had failed.

Apart from that, the best suggesting I can make is to run the client-side code in a debugger or add more trace-printing or logging.  (For example, look at what `Socket.isClosed()` returns at various points ....)

Comment: Of course you are right with the threads being useless but they are needed on Android. When I dont do them, I receive the NetworkOnMainThread thing. Of course this should prevent me from blocking the UI but as I am sure that the networking doenst take a lot of time, I do the join instantly.

Comment: @MrPixelDream - You are solving that problem the wrong way then.  Because the `join` is going to block the UI thread anyway!

Comment: Uh I guess I didn't write my thoughts the right way. I am aware of this but I know for sure that the content of this thread doesnt take longer than a half second.

Comment: `500 ms * 60 frames per second = 30 skipped frames`. Also the user will see and realize that the app does not react for half a second. Beside that you can **never** say for sure how long a code for network access will take...

Comment: Thanks for this hint, after fixing the Socket thing, I will have a look over the threading.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that *you* closed the socket. It doesn't indicate that the peer has disconnected.

So, it's a logic flaw in your code. You are indeed closing the socket at at least one point.

I suggest setting the socket to null after you do that. Then this exception will become an NPE, and you'll *have* to fix that :-|

NB closing either the input stream or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: I used your approach setting the socket to `null` after closing it in all places where I close the socket (2 to be precise). Sadly, it didn't help - I keep getting the SocketException instead of the NPE.